# Read data with space character in R

Tags: r, input, character, space

Usually, `read.table` will solve many data input problems personally. Like this one:

```
China 2 3
USA 1 4
```

Sometimes, the data can madden people, like:

```
Chia 2 3
United States 3 4
```

So the `read.table` cannot work, and any assistance is appreciated.

P.S. the format of data file is .dat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set up some test data:

```
# create test data
cat("Chia 2 3
United States 3 4
", file = "file.with.spaces.txt")
```

**1)** Using the above read in the data, insert commas between fields and re-read:

```
L <- readLines("file.with.spaces.txt")
L2 <- sub("^(.*) +(\\S+) +(\\S+)$", "\\1,\\2,\\3", L) # 1
DF <- read.table(text = L2, sep = ",")
```

giving:

```
> DF
             V1 V2 V3
1          Chia  2  3
2 United States  3  4
```

**2)** Another approach.  Using L from above, replace the last string of spaces with comma twice (since there are three fields):

```
 L2 <- L
 for(i in 1:2) L2 <- sub(" +(\\S+)$", ",\\1", L2) # 2
 DF <- read.table(text = L2, sep = ",")
```

**ADDED** second solution.  Minor improvements.

Comment: That's an elegant solution. Care to elaborate on how you exactly find and replace the spaces. I know that 'sub' finds and replaces strings, but not confident with the expressions within.

Comment: The regex in line #1 starts at the beginning (^) slurps up anything it can find (possibly including spaces) until it finds spaces " +" followed by non-spaces \\S+ followed by spaces followed by non-spaces followed by tne end of line ($).  The parenthesized portions of the matched expression can be referenced in the replacement string as "\\1", "\\2", etc.  In the regex #2 we match spaces " +" followed by non-spaces \\S+ followed by end of string ($) and replace with a comma followed by the parenthesized portion in the match.

Answer (score 1):

If the column seperator 'sep' is indeed a whitespace, it logically cannot differentiate between spaces in a name and spaces that actually seperate between columns. I'd suggest to change your country names to single strings, ie, strings without spaces. Alternatively, use semicolons to seperate between your data colums and use:

```
data <- read.table(foo.dat, sep= ";")
```

If you have many rows in your .dat file, you can consider using regular expressions to find spaces between the columns and replace them with semicolons.